# How can i get elements in select using by example, whereDoesntHave in Laravel 8 and Filament?

Tags: pivot-table, laravel-filament

I've three tables Users, company and user_company (pivot). I need to, for example, associate users to a company in a form using select that show me only the user are nit associated to this company.
Could anybody help me?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

check the Filaments Documentation on the relationshipmanager AND
#Attaching and detaching records either manually or by --attach when creating the relationship manager

Ensure withPivot is included in the EloquentModel and check the getRelations in the modelresource

Answer (score 0):

See docs #Populating automatically from a relationship

This works for me:

```
Forms\Components\Select::make('companyId')
                ->multiple()
                ->relationship('companies','company_name'),
```